# How to attract students under Erasmus

Tags: research-process, europe

I am new to Europe and have a well funded research project (but limited funding for human resource). Since the topic is very interesting, I though I can attract some graduate students to join my group under Erasmus program.

I appreciate if you give me some hints, where and how should I advertise that I accept graduate students (funded by Erasmus) to join my research project.

Comment: Can you indicate if you are a principal investigator on this project? Are you a professor?

Comment: What do you mean by "join" your group. Any graduate student will already have a project "at home". "Join", would thus really be colaborate. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, Erasmus research projects are available to other students through network that your institution has with other universities. People who are responsible and actually paid to do promotion should be ERASMUS administrative officer at your institution, but if you for some reasons cannot rely on them, I suggest you to use ESN, ( Erasmus Student Network, organisation ) They can advertise and offer your vacancies to students,  this service suppose to be for free,
other way, maybe more time existing, is to contact collaborating universities from your network, and invite their students to take a look on your project.